# .htacces redirect for mobile should only affect the landing page

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

I redirected all mobile devices to the mobile site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.**homepagename**.at$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]


RewriteRule .? http://m.**homepagename**.at  [L,R=302]
```

the problem about this is, that on the mobile side some buttons redirect to the normal Homepage and this redirect overwrites that so you stay on the mainpage of the mobile site because the site dont exists in mobile

what ive to change about this redirect to affect only the landing page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what ive to change about this redirect to affect only the landing page ?

Just change your `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://m.**homepagename**.at [L,R=302]
```

in order to target only home/landing page.